# How do I deploy octopress 3 to a subdirectory within an existing gh-pages site?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

I am using Octopress 3, and when I run `jekyll build`, it generates the correct set of files (which includes my static files, see list of files below):

```
      $ cd _site
:_site$ ls -a
.               CNAME               assets              google2d8.html  index-alternative.html
..              about               blog                increase-revenue.html       index.html
```

Note that my entire jekyll-generated `blog` is now safely stored within `\blog\`, which is how I want it.

But once I do `octopress deploy`, it overwrites this entire folder (which also overwrites my existing static files), see listing below:

```
      $ cd _site
:_site$ ls -a
.       ..      Gemfile     Gemfile.lock    about       css     feed.xml    index.html  jekyll
```

Here is my `_config.yml`:

```
title: My Title
email: some@email.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
     some description
baseurl: "/blog" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://example.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: myusername

source: '../'

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
```

This is my `_deploy.yml`

```
method: git                 # How do you want to deploy? git, rsync or s3.
site_dir: _site             # Location of your static site files.
git_url: my_git_url

git_branch: gh-pages-2       # Git branch where static site files are commited
```

**Note:** Once I remove the following line from my `_config.yml`:     `source: '../'`, my `jekyll build` generates that deploy folder like `octopress deploy` does.

Given the new Octopress 3 and an existing static site hosted on my `gh-pages` branch, how do I deploy my blog to a subdirectory of that existing `gh-pages` site?

Comment: what exactly do you want to fix? You can run a shell script at any point to rearrange your file directory.

Comment: Whenever I run `octopress deploy`, it keeps overwriting the files that `jekyll build` creates. It's not about any random shell scripts. It's about the workflow of Octopress and Jekyll.

Comment: @maxpleaner Basically what I am trying to do is, I have an existing static site hosted on GH-pages and I would like to add a blog to a subdirectory `/blog` on that site. I can't figure out how to prevent `octopress deploy` from overwriting the entire repo, as opposed to just the subdirectory `/blog`. Is that more clear?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get that from the post - what do you want to achieve? You want `octopress deploy` to generate all files into `_site/blog` directory?

Comment: @marcamillion, i see this has ended but you may consider reading this. http://albertlatham.com/archive/Octopress_3_git_workflow/

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the root dir correctly.
Follow this instruction:
http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/

Comment: Care to illustrate what the correct setting would look like for my project, i.e. with code?